# Is my friend's money safe in a UK bank?

Tags: united-kingdom

My friend has 50K in personal bank account.

He also has 50K in his company bank account. Bank account is opened by only 1 director however company has his wife as director as well.

Both accounts are with same bank.

I also have a joint account with my wife and it has 2K.

I also have another account with another bank and have 2K in it.

I changed numbers up and down to avoid people stealing my information.

Is my money safe given that Bank of england changed rate to 0.1% or 1%, one of them.

Comment: Why do you think the money would not be safe?

Comment: Why would a rate change risk the money's safety?

Comment: What would happen if banks go bust ? my friend going to loose money then ?

Comment: The 50k in a personal account will be protected by the government (financial services compensation scheme) which can compensate per person per financial institution up to £85k

Comment: @n34_panda what about company account, thanks

Comment: I am afraid I am no expert which is why I didn’t provide an answer, I just knew the above as I have capital in a personal U.K. account too. I would say give the FSCS site a read as it may have all your answers: https://www.fscs.org.uk/check-your-money-is-protected/